# 'operator<<' must return value?

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors

Getting compiler error c4716 ('operator<<' must return value) in Visual Studio 2019 from this block of code:

```
// Friend function to print the towers to stream
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const TheGame& game) {
stream
    << "Tower #0:" << game.towers[0] << endl
    << "Tower #1:" << game.towers[1] << endl
    << "Tower #2:" << game.towers[2] << endl
    ;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `return` with any value in your code. As the error says, your `operator<<` must return a value (probably the original stream in your case so more stream operations can be chained to it, i.e. `return stream;`).

`2 << 3` would return `16` for instance. And `stream << something` usually returns `stream` so that you can add more `<<` operations at the end on its return value. Since you are implementing your own `operator<<` you need to take care of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Friend function to print the towers to stream
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const TheGame& game) {
    return stream
        << "Tower #0:" << game.towers[0] << endl
        << "Tower #1:" << game.towers[1] << endl
        << "Tower #2:" << game.towers[2] << endl
        ;
}
```